# Find the limit of $\frac{2+\sqrt{2U_n^2+4U_n+4}}{U_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

Given a sequence $\{U_n\}$ such that $U_1>0$ and:
\begin{align}U_{n+1}=\frac{2+\sqrt{2U_n^2+4U_n+4}}{U_n}\end{align}
Find the limit of $\{U_n\}$

It's easy when you know that $U_n$ has a limit, then it would be straightforward swapping $\lim_{n\to \infty} U_n=L$ into the equation, which yields $L= \sqrt3 +1$

However, how do I prove $U_n$ has a limit?

I have tried considering the reciprocal of $U_n$, or $V_n=\frac1{U_n}$, and got that the sequence jumps back and forth.

How can this be done?

Many thanks!

Comment: Instead of given formula, I would look at $$U_n=\dfrac{4(U_{n+1}+1)}{U_{n+1}^2-2}.$$ Note that the denominator is never zero for any choice of $U_1>0.$

Comment: @Bumblebee Thanks man, that's tricky rather but I hope it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking up where you left off:

\begin{align}
V_n=\frac{1}{2a_n+\sqrt{1+(2a_n+1)^2}}
\end{align}

which means that $0<V_n<1$.

Now consider the two sub-sequences of $V_n$, which are $V_{2k}$ and $V_{2k+1}$, we have one of them must increase and the other must decrease.

Then by Weierstrass theorem, $V_{2k}$ and $V_{2k+1}$ converges.

Now it only remains to prove that $\lim V_{2k} = \lim V_{2k+1}$, but this would be straightforward since they have the same formula.

Hence, $\lim U_n = L$ exists. $\square$